# Remove pesky image border

Tags: html, css

I for the life of me can't find anyone who knows the answer to this.

Look at http://granthoneymoon.com/notifications.html, the spacer images have borders around them. Now, I can just use empty div's instead of spacer images, but I'm using them here to illustrate the point. This happens elsewhere as well.

You can see a picture of the borders [HERE](http://granthoneymoon.com/screenshots.png).

I've used "border: none" in several different ways, but it makes no difference. I don't have a border on ANY images on my entire site.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="main_title">Friend Activity</div>
<div class="notifications_container"><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"><a href="#"><img src="images/notification-prayer-0.png" class="notifications_button"></a><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"><a href="#"><img src="images/notification-answer-2.png" class="notifications_button"></a><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"><a href="#"><img src="images/notification-posts-1.png" class="notifications_button"></a><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"></div>

<div class="main_title">Communication</div>
<div class="notifications_container"><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"><a href="#"><img src="images/notifications-request-2.png" class="notifications_button2"></a><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"><a href="#"><img src="images/notifications-comments-2.png" class="notifications_button2"></a><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"><a href="#"><img src="images/notifications-messages-2.png" class="notifications_button2"></a><img src="images/none.png" class="notifications_spacer"></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
img {
   border:none;
}

.notifications_container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 840px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
@media and (max-width: 799px) {
.notifications_container {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 386px) {
.notifications_container img {
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.notifications_spacer {
    width: 10% !important;
    height: 5px !important;
    border: none !important;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 385px) {
.notifications_container img {
    width: 26.66%;
    height: auto;
}

.notifications_spacer {
    width: 5% !important;
    height: 5px !important;
    border: none !important;
}

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using margins on your buttons instead of using empty elements for spacing?

Comment: The border is appearing because the image is not, apparently, linked correctly (or is missing) from the site. **Internal Server Error** - http://granthoneymoon.com/images/none.png

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using images to space things? but... Create a transparent gif or png and use that instead of no image at all.
images/none.png < does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Change the style to:

```
.notifications_spacer {
    width: 10% !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;        
}
```

Note that the height is 0. This does not affect the use of a spacer image, and the height seems to be causing the outline.